# Margins of the page are different in ejs file and html file, and background is gray when it should be white

Tags: html, css, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

The margins of the page are different when I compare the html file (in the browser) and the ejs file. I am using node/express and Bootstrap 4. I built the page initially in html. I wanted the content to fill the page from side edge to side edge, and I was able to do that with the html page.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
{
    margin:0;
}
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-lg-12 pl-5 pr-5 pb-5 pt-5 text-light" style="font-size:30px; background-color: pink;">
         My Website
     </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This will produce a div that is a band of pink color that goes from one edge of the screen to the other edge.

However, when I take the same html page and change it to an ejs file, there is about 1.3 cm of white space between the div and the edge of the screen. Not only that, but the background of white divs becomes a very pale gray background.

I didn't add any other css styling to make the background color change to this pale gray color. And this pale gray background only appears with ejs files, not with html files.

I do not have a partials ejs file except for one that contains messages, and that ejs file has no styling information. Every main page, eg, home page, about page, etc, is supposed to be self-contained in terms of css and html.

I do not know where the gray background is coming from.

Bootstrap (I'm using Bootstrap 4) is working fine for me. There were problems opening dropdown menus initially but I fixed that by downloading Bootstrap and putting the css file into the Public folder instead of using a cdn link to Bootstrap, but anyway the margin problem was there even before I did that.

Comment: Maybe adding a reset stylesheet might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it sounds odd so I just doubled checked using my Bootstrap 4 template. It works very well the pink background run left edge to right edge no white spaces. Full template below for your ref. I expect it is smt with software installation. You need to make sure Bootstrap, jQuery, popper.js are all installed properly in your project anyhow. Let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <!-- build:css css/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row"> 
           <div class="col-lg-12 pl-5 pr-5 pb-5 pt-5 text-light" style="font-size:30px; background-color: pink;">
               My Website
           </div>
        </div> 
      </div> 

   
    
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <!-- build:js js/main.js -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you need guide for install node js, npm, BS, jQuery, popper.js, let me know. I will type down the commands

Comment: I will try your suggestion but I think at the end of the day, the problem is with my browser and/or my computer. I am using a macbook 12 inch, 10.13.4 (Mac OS High Sierra) and the browser is Chrome 89, which is the latest. I noticed that container-fluid and jumbtron do not show up as full width in html when testing with browser. The only way I can get full width is as above in the question: ```<div><div class="row">``` I will test on other screens to see whether it's a mac issue. Thank you. @hang-coder

Comment: @ddmmcc Thank you for adding the "Run code snippet" navbar. Can you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

BS has 2 classes "container" and "container-fluid" you need class "container-fluid" to force the content expand left edge to right edge. Code below should solve the issue. Let me know if all good after.

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-lg-12 pl-5 pr-5 pb-5 pt-5 text-light" style="font-size:30px; background-color: pink;">
         My Website
     </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. In fact it leaves even more white space on the sides. @hang-coder

Answer (score 1):

your code works just the fine for me, make sure you have written your backend code properly like this

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('home', {Title: 'Welcome'});
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Make sure your EJS file is in a folder called 'views' and you have your css file in a folder called 'public'

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is. It is the `express-ejs-layouts` module that I installed and used. I forgot I had done that and that's why I didn't mention this in the question. I also didn't think it would affect the layout so much, and I thought I had to install this as well as the `ejs` module for `ejs` to work properly. To be honest, I didn't know what the `express-ejs-layouts` module did.

Once I removed `const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')` and the `app.use(expressLayouts)` middleware, the ejs files render fine now. The margins are flush with the edge of the page with `container-fluid`. There is no pale gray background anymore.

I also have to mention that the solution suggested by hang-coder above of putting the stylesheets in the correct order worked for the html files. Even though that was not the main question, it solved the issue of the html files not showing margins correctly in the browser when using `container-fluid`. I had wrongly put the Bootstrap scripts above the jQuery scripts. I had put those scripts in the wrong order in the ejs files too, and that was also part of the problem for why the margins were not displaying properly, but I corrected the order just before I asked the margins question in the ejs files because I had to do that to make the dropdown menu work, which was another problem I had just before I asked the margins question, but I wasn't sure whether they made a difference to the margins issue.

So the problem had nothing to do with mac screens or how Chrome browser displays in macs, as I originally thought.

This script is showing the correct margins in html files for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">. 
    </script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">. 
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
      <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
      <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So in summary, placing the jQuery and Bootstrap scripts in the correct order and removing the `express-ejs-layouts` solved the problem.